# Cleaner way to provide different href URLs on ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using hide and show to display different href links on ng-repeat depending if the userid exists on routeParams. The image inside the href tag is the same for both conditions.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="trip in trips">
    // If userid exists, the user is authenticated so provide userid on url
    <a ng-show="userid" ng-href="#/trip/{{trip.tripid}}/user/{{userid}}">
        // Same exact image as in ng-hide
        <img ng-src="trip.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Trip Photo">
    </a>
   // If userid does not exist, the user is not authenticated so no userid on url
    <a ng-hide="userid" ng-href="#/trip/{{trip.tripid}}/">
        // Same exact image as in ng-show
        <img ng-src="trip.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Trip Photo">
    </a>
</div>
```

I feel there is a less redundant way to avoid using ng-show and ng-hide just to change the URL and writing duplicate image tags inside the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filter and pass the data, as such:

```
filter('urlFormatter', function() {
    return function(tripid, userId) {
        if(angular.isDefined(userId)) {
            return "#/trip/"+tripid+"/user/"+userId;
        }
        return "#/trip/"+tripid+"/";
    }
});
```

Then use it in your attribute as:

```
ng-href="trip.tripid | urlFormatter:userid"
```

Or

```
ng-href="trip.tripid | urlFormatter"
```

You can also use the $location service and change your path:

```
$location.path('/path/foo/bar')
```

With this method, you would bind an ng-click to the  tag and apply the location logic within the controller, that is, if the userid is passed.

An example:

```
<a ng-click="goSomewhere(trip.tripid, userid)">
```

Where the controller would be

```
controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.goSomewhere = function(tripid, userid) {
        if(angular.isDefined(userid) {
            $location.path("/trip/"+tripid+"/user/"+userid);
        }
        else {
            $location.path("/trip/"+tripid+"/");
        } 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rastii! I will be using the filter approach!